# Force Unity to do a check for a collision with triggers

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collider

I want to instantstiate an object into my scene, and when it's instanstiated I want the object spawned in to do a collision check with the triggers on that object, however if I just spawn the object in, Unity won't do a collision check, unless I move this object and its trigger collider outside the collision and make them recollide.

A nice workaround would be to force unity to do this trigger/collider check but it won't do it unless I move the object out of the collision. I've tried OnTriggerEnter as well as OnTriggerStay but non of them work.

Is there a way to force unity to run Trigger functions in code or something similar?

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

you could use the [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) system and check for a overlap, so for a box that would be [Physic.OverlapBox(center, halfExtents, orientation, layerMask, queryTriggerInteraction)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html)

Comment: @Artyu, did this work???